# How do you add the scrapy framework to portable python?

Tags: python, scrapy, portable-python

I need to create a portable python install on a usb but also install the scrapy framework on it, so I can work on and run my spiders on any computer.
Has anyone else done this? Is it even possible?
If so how do you add scrapy onto the portable python usb and then run the spiders?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can easily download scrapy executable, extract it with python, copy scrapy folder and content to **c:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Lib\site-packages\** and you'll have scrapy in your portable python.
I just had my similar problem with SciKit this way.